# simple useState Array map()

Tags: reactjs

hi I'm practicing a react hook  and i can't get `useState` value here's code 
i can get `number.value` but 
i can't get `number.newOne.new`
 What did I do wrong?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'


function App() {
  const [values] = useState([
    {
      value: 0,
      newOne: [
        {
          new: 'he'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      value: 1,
      newOne: [
        {
          new: 'she'
        }
      ]
    }
  ])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {values.map(number => (
          <>
            <div>{number.value}</div> {/* this is good */}
            <div>{number.newOne.new}</div> {/* this is not work */}
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: `newOne` is an array.. perhaps you might want to iterate it (using `.map()` as you did before), or, if it will always be just one element, not using an array at all

Answer (score 0):

The `newOne` is an array, you have to aplly to the first element like this:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {values.map(number => (
          <>
            <div>{number.value}</div> {/* this is good */}
            <div>{number.newOne[0].new}</div> {/* this is not work */}
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

If could be more then one element, you're supposed to iterate  with `.map()`.

Hope it helps.